# Alljoyn Android : Connect device using Alljoyn

Tags: android, connection, alljoyn

Whether the sample chat or file transfer apk provided in the alljoyn-android sdk work by default when we install them or we need to do some changes .  I tried with Chat and File transfer apk but dint successed . Any one know how to use them ? .   In chat application I am able to create channels on Single device  and can join channels on a Single device , how would I make the daemon running .  How would I make two device connect each other . DOes it require any other extra stuff rather than just importing and running the project .  In the recent SDK there is no Alljoyn.apk neither the bundle.jar which is mentioned in one of the videos.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of AllJoyn there is no longer a need to have the AllJoyn.apk or the bundled.jar.  The default behavior is to start up daemon like services as part of the application as default.  Nothing additional should be needed.

If you are having problems talking between two devices.  Make sure they are both connected to the same hub and network isolation is not turned on.

Comment: *"and network isolation is not turned on"* is very important. Further, it's an major limitation if you don't control the network.